# Vue Js and Spring Boot Basic Authentication

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, basic-authentication

I have a basic Spring Boot API with Spring Security enabled. When accessing a secured resource from within Vue (using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)), the browser will request me for username and password with an "Authorization Required" pop-up. After that, the credentials seem to be stored by the browser and I can just keep on making requests.

How should I bypass the authentication process made by the browser and replace it with one made and controlled directly by Vue Js?

Comment: If you really want to keep basic-authentication you will need to send an Authentication Header with your requests. You can define interceptors in axios to ensure they are sent with every request. However I'd prefer to use cookies / jwt tokens for authentication.

Comment: I assume I would have to configure Spring Boot to handle JWT then? Know any reference for this?

Comment: I think this explains it very well : http://www.svlada.com/jwt-token-authentication-with-spring-boot/ - however - if you are new to auth and vue I'd suggest you try to send the Basic Auth Header with every request in a first attempt to get into the topic. You will not need a lot of code and it's a good training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First, add security configuration (Assuming you are using Spring Security):

```
@Configuration
public class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(apiAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint apiAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        ApiBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new ApiBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName("Api Server");
        return entryPoint;
    }

    public static class ApiBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

        @Override
        public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
            response.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"" + getRealmName() + "\"");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            //response.setContentType("");
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.writeValue(writer, ApiDataGenerator.buildResult(
                    ErrorCode.AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED, "Authorization failed"));
        }

    }
}
```

### Second, Add authentication in the http request header in following format:

- `Authorization: Basic qwerasdfzxcv`
- `qwerasdfzxcv` is base64 hash that encode by `username:password`